# How to check if session is started and redirect user?

Tags: php, html, mysql, session

I am trying to create a snippet of PHP that checks if the user has signed up using Sessions when they reach my index page, and if they haven't, I will redirect them to the signup page.

I have started the Session after the user has signed up, but I can't seem to check on my index page to check if the session has started or not.

Sign up PHP:

```
    session_start();

    //create connection

    //check for errors in the form

    if(!$error) {

        //insert values from form to sql database

        $_SESSION['login_user'] = $username;

        //email user


    }
?>
```

index.php

```
<?PHP

    include("signupphp.php");

    if(!$username) {

        echo '<script>location.href = "https://google.com";</script>';

    }

 ?>
```

Ideally, I would want when the user signs up, it creates the session, and whenever they go to the `index.php`, it checks to see whether they have signed up, and if they haven't, it will redirect them to the signup page.

Comment: why is this tagged as "mysql" and "html"?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding you correctly you want to check if the session has been set with the username, correct?

In that case you're checking the wrong variable.

```
if( !isset($_SESSION["login_user"]) ){
    header("Location: https://google.com");
    exit();
}
```

This should do the trick. I also changed your redirect to a PHP redirect.

Answer (score 0):

The sessions will propagate between the pages of your site. So, in sign up:

```
$username = $_POST['username']//The username could be obtained from a login form
sesion_start();
$_SESSION['login_user'] = $username;
$_SESSION['valid'] = true;
```

will keep `$username` available for index.php

```
session_start()
if( ! $_SESSION['valid']){
    echo '<script>location.href = "https://google.com";</script>';
}
```